# How to sort a multi-dimensional tensor using the returned indices of tf.nn.top_k?

Tags: tensorflow

I have two multi-dimensional tensors `a` and `b`. And I want to sort them by the values of `a`.

I found [`tf.nn.top_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/nn/evaluation#top_k) is able to sort a tensor and return the indices which is used to sort the input. How can I use the returned indices from `tf.nn.top_k(a, k=2)` to sort `b`?

For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.reshape(tf.range(30), (2, 5, 3))
b = tf.reshape(tf.range(210), (2, 5, 3, 7))
k = 2
sorted_a, indices = tf.nn.top_k(a, k)

# How to sort b into
# sorted_b[0, 0, 0, :] = b[0, 0, indices[0, 0, 0], :]
# sorted_b[0, 0, 1, :] = b[0, 0, indices[0, 0, 1], :]
# sorted_b[0, 1, 0, :] = b[0, 1, indices[0, 1, 0], :]
# ...
```

---

#### Update

Combining [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#gather_nd) with [`tf.meshgrid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#meshgrid) can be one solution. For example, the following code is tested on python 3.5 with tensorflow `1.0.0-rc0`:

```
a = tf.reshape(tf.range(30), (2, 5, 3))
b = tf.reshape(tf.range(210), (2, 5, 3, 7))
k = 2

sorted_a, indices = tf.nn.top_k(a, k)

shape_a = tf.shape(a)
auxiliary_indices = tf.meshgrid(*[tf.range(d) for d in (tf.unstack(shape_a[:(a.get_shape().ndims - 1)]) + [k])], indexing='ij')

sorted_b = tf.gather_nd(b, tf.stack(auxiliary_indices[:-1] + [indices], axis=-1))
```

However, I wonder if there is a solution which is more readable and doesn't need to create `auxiliary_indices` above.

Comment: As you said, it should be possible to work it out using [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#gather_nd), possibly in combination with [`tf.meshgrid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#meshgrid), but after a while trying I have not been able...

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for sharing `tf.meshgrid`. I update the question with one possible solution.

Comment: That's great, I may actually need that myself at some point! :) It's okay to leave the question open if you still want a better solution but, just in case you don't know (which maybe you do), [it is okay to answer you own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a problem.

```
b = tf.reshape(tf.range(60), (2, 5, 3, 7))
```

Because TensorFlow Cannot reshape a tensor with 60 elements to shape [2,5,3,7] (210 elements).
And you can't sort a rank 4 tensor (b) using indices of rank 3 tensors.

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo. I have corrected the mistake. ( `tf.reshape(tf.range(210), (2, 5, 3, 7))` ). When `b` is a rank 2 tensor and the `indices` is a rank 1 tensor, `tf.gather(b, indices)` can solve the problem. When `indices` is a tensor with the rank > 1, I thought `tf.gather_nd` can help, but it will need to generate some auxiliary indices as the input of `tf.gather_nd`. I wonder if there is a more flexible and more efficient solution.