# Gather elements along second dimension of tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Assume `values` and tensor `T` both have shape `(N,K)`. Now if we think of them in terms of matrices, I would like for each row of `T` to get the row element corresponding to the index where `values` has it's maximum. I can easily find those indices with

```
max_indicies = tf.argmax(T, 1)
```

which returns a tensor of shape `(N)`. Now, how can I gather up these indices from `T` such that I get something of shape `N`? I tried

```
result = tf.gather(T,max_indices)
```

but it doesn't do the right thing - it returns something of shape `(N,K)` which means that it didn't gather up anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [tf.gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#gather_nd).

For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

values = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0, 1],
                      [0, 1, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 1, 0]])

T = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2 ,  3],
                 [4, 5, 6 ,  7],
                 [8, 9, 10, 11]])

max_indices = tf.argmax(values, axis=1)
# If T.get_shape()[0] is None, you can replace it with tf.shape(T)[0].
result = tf.gather_nd(T, tf.stack((tf.range(T.get_shape()[0], 
                                            dtype=max_indices.dtype),
                                   max_indices),
                                  axis=1))

print(result.eval())
```

However when the ranks of `values` and `T` are higher, the use of `tf.gather_nd` will be a little awkward. I posted my current solution on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897212/how-to-sort-a-multi-dimensional-tensor-using-the-returned-indices-of-tf-nn-top-k). There might be a better solution in case of high dimensional `values` and `T`.

Comment: Thank you kind sir.